# How to add values to a shapefile field with a list with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am trying to add values to a field that believes in shp "clasific" with data from a list "clasi".
The code I try to use is the following, but in the function SetAttribute () it tells me that the second argument cannot be of this type. I don't know if there is another way to do it.

```
ruta = "C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/crudo/TF-FLORENCIA-221_7246_1003.shp"
vlayer= QgsVectorLayer(ruta) ## crea el shp de la ruta

######### add field (columna) a shp
campo= vlayer.dataProvider()  
campo.addAttributes([QgsField("clasific", QVariant.String),
                     QgsField("area",QVariant.Double)])
vlayer.updateFields()  ### actualizar

f=QgsFeature()
f.setAttributes(clasi)

####### Add values  to the field
for feature in vlayer.getFeatures():
    vlayer.startEditing()
    feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex("clasific"),f)
    vlayer.updateFeature(feature)
    iface.vectorLayerTools().stopEditing(vlayer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can identify several problems in your request:

```
f.setAttributes(clasi)
```

You assign your entity a list. What you have to do is make a loop on your list and then assign a value from your list to the entity.

You start and close the edit mode in a loop. You can do this off-loop and therefore do each action only once.

Execute your request step by step to check that you get the right result.

Comment: add the list in the entity because if I put it directly I get: AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'clasi.

vlayer.startEditing()
for feature in vlayer.getFeatures():
    feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex("clasific"),feature.clasi)
    vlayer.updateFeature(feature)

Comment: `vlayer.startEditing()
for feature in vlayer.getFeatures(): feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex("clasific"),feature.clasi) vlayer.updateFeature(feature)`